# Regex in C# Console App

Tags: c#, regex, substring

```
"Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472 - ActorID: 120706813"

"Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472"

"Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472 "
```

I am new in regex C# what will be regex to extract tweet Id `436660665219305472` from sample string 1 & string 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex, you can use Split method and LINQ to get what you want :

```
var input = "Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472 - ActorID: 120706813";

var output = input.Split().First(x => x.All(char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. I upvote it, I think it was really clever!

Comment: This solutions breaks if the part before "TweetID" (is it some kind of title?) happens to contain a number.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [named grouping construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) for .NET

Here's an example that matches your scenario.

```
string str1 = "Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472 - ActorID: 120706813";

string str2 = "Fire hose Tweet - TweetID: 436660665219305472";

var tweetIdRegex = new Regex(@"TweetID:\s(?<TweetID>\d+)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);

Console.WriteLine(tweetIdRegex.Match(str1).Value);
Console.WriteLine(tweetIdRegex.Match(str2).Value);
```

Output:

```
TweetID: 436660665219305472
TweetID: 436660665219305472
```

Alternatively, if you end up with a regular expression that represents the entire string, and you're using grouping constructs, you could do the following, which is why I mentioned named grouping constructs. This is a technique I've used extensively.

```
GroupCollection tweetInfo = tweetIdRegex.Match(str1).Groups;
Console.WriteLine(tweetInfo["TweetID"].Value);
```

in which case it would output:

```
436660665219305472
```